# rhel + eth0: Detected Tx Unit Hang

Tags: networking, rhel, kernel, vmware, dmesg

**Dear friends and college**

we have VM machines with rhel 7.2 version - `3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64`

we noticed about the following messages ( from `/var/log/messages` )

```
 e1000 0000:02:01.0 eth0: Detected Tx Unit Hang#012  Tx Queue             <0>#012  TDH                  <45>#012  TDT
```

and from dmesg we get that

```
[21519947.519425] e1000 0000:02:01.0 eth0: Detected Tx Unit Hang
  Tx Queue             <0>
  TDH                  <45>
  TDT                  <45>
  next_to_use          <26>
  next_to_clean        <45>
buffer_info[next_to_clean]
  time_stamp           <6032d5901>
  next_to_watch        <47>
  jiffies              <6032d75ab>
  next_to_watch.status <0>
[21519949.521583] e1000 0000:02:01.0 eth0: Detected Tx Unit Hang
  Tx Queue             <0>
  TDH                  <45>
  TDT                  <45>
  next_to_use          <26>
  next_to_clean        <45>
buffer_info[next_to_clean]
  time_stamp           <6032d5901>
  next_to_watch        <47>
  jiffies              <6032d7d7e>
  next_to_watch.status <0>
[21519949.811366] e1000 0000:02:01.0 eth0: Reset adapter
[21519949.855081] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
```

we try to search the solution for the problem above and we see post about the following fixing

set following in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and reboot machine

```
pcie_aspm=offet ( https://serverfault.com/questions/193114/linux-e1000e-intel-networking-driver-problems-galore-where-do-i-start )
```

or

```
ethtool -K eth0 tso off gso off
```

or

changed the network adapters tor `VMNETX3.`

and so on ....

so we are confuse about the right solution

please advice what is the right approach for our problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with older kernels ([Bugzilla 1288237](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1288237)).  The fix has been backported into newer kernsla and is tracked under the following security advisories:

- [RHSA-2020:1016](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2020:1016)
- [RHSA-2019:3979](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2019:3979)

This problem is believed to have been introduced by the following upstream commit:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b4ded8327fea82b53fcec39e0845011246d020f4

With kernels older than 3.10.0-514.el7, some users report that the behavior stops occurring when the Scatter-Gather offload engine on the affected interface was disabled via ethtool:

```
# ethtool -K <interface> sg off
```

For more information check out the Knowledgebase article from Red Hat: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2070703

In general, due to the stable ABI and API interfaces provided by RHEL there is seldom any benefit in running out of date software and one should update to the latest patch release for the major version being run (e.g. RHEL 7, RHEL &).

Comment: about RHSA-2020:1016 , is it possible to download this errata by yumdownloader ( from redhat subscriber-manager ) ?

Comment: I see it from - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526659/yumdownloader-the-rpm-for-redhat-7-3

Comment: @jessica, As of RHEL7 and beyond you no longer even need `yumdownloader`.  The plugin `downloadonly` was added to the main yum package.  Thus, you should be able to run:  `yum update --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp --advisory=RHSA-2020:1016` to retrieve the relevant package.  Just make sure that plugins are enabled (they are by default) so that yum can also use the subscription-manager plugin.